# Object object when rendering JSON using EJS

Tags: node.js, json, ejs

I'm a newbie to NodeJS and I'm using this API https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers to render it using EJS on my website. The server code I wrote is as follows

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    let url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers";
    try{
        request.get(url,{},(err, resp, body)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                let jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(jsonObject['wrxinr']['sell']);
                res.render("home.ejs", {"data":jsonObject});
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({message:"Something went wrong."});
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

and my `home.ejs` file is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wazirx Tickers API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% if(data != undefined) { %>
            <% for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) { %>
                <p><%= data[i] %></p>
            <% } %>
        <% } else{ %>
            <h4>sorry, cannot find what you wanted!</h4>
        <% } %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can access `wrxinr` object using this `data['wrxinr']['sell']` snippet. But, I want to render every Token on the webpage. How do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the object and display every propertie on it, i think there is a way, maybe at first try to loop over every propertie of an object

Comment: umm thanks, but how do I do it. I'm new to JSON, I didn't quite understand what you said. Could you please provide some pseudo code or something?